# 301 Redirect specific page with ModX Evo

Tags: url, redirect, http-status-code-301, modx, modx-evolution

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want to redirect the url /sale to the new one /gift-sales So I have added this to the above:

```
RewriteCond %(THE-REQUEST)^sale$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gift-sales [R=30,L]
```

In the ModX backend I have, of course, changed the alias to gift-sales, but I cannot seem to get the redirect working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 RewriteRule ^/sale  http://www.mydomain.com/gift-sales [R=301,L]
```